# Liquid maths: calculating a percent discount in the order notification email template

Tags: shopify, liquid

Why is this returning 0?

```
{% if discounts %}
  Discount
  {{ discounts_amount | divided_by: subtotal_price | times: 100 }}%
{% endif %}
```

I have also tried accommodating integer maths, but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong syntax. Try this

```
{% if discounts %}
  Discount {{ discounts.amount | divided_by: subtotal_price | times: 100 }}%
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Note that if `discounts.amount` and `subtotal_price` are both integers, the output will be an integer (truncated, not rounded). One way to ensure a decimal is to change `times: 100` to `times: 100.0` and put it before the `divided_by` filter: `{{ discounts.amount | times: 100.0 | divided_by: subtotal_price }}`.

Comment: The answer supplied still results in 0. Thanks for the comment, @Nick -- I'll see if that works.

Comment: I just noticed `discounts_amount` in your question was changed to `discounts.amount` in @HymnZ's answer and thus my comment. Is that what's causing it to be zero?

Answer (score 0):

It may have been a long time but I'm still replying because of the many views.

We have to convert integer to float

```
{% assign my_integer = 7 %}
{% assign my_float = my_integer | times: 1.0 %}
{{ 20 | divided_by: my_float }}
```

https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/divided_by/